# Find the RDF mappings from the given RDF(.ttl) files and get the output in JSON

Tags: java, json, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I am Rakesh. I am working on semantic web and came across a issue. I have 10 .ttl(Turtle) files. I need to find the mappings from these files and display the output in JSON format. The entire project must be like a standalone application.

I googled for the solution. I found out that I need to find APIs to do the mapping. Then I think I need to write  a Java program to get the JSON output.I am new to semantic web and need some help from you. Please guys help me.

Rakesh

Comment: What do you mean by “find the mappings”? Mapping from what to what? And how do you want to “find” them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jena. It's currently an Apache project and provides you with a powerful library for working with RDF models and graphs alongside much more.

You can find it here: http://jena.apache.org/

This page in the documentation (RDF I/O) is probably all you need for now: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/iohowto.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you call "mapping". If you want to list the statements (Subject-Predicate-Object triples), it's one of the most fundamental things Jena helps you to do. Using Jena you can create a RDF model from its serialized form, of which Turtle is just one of the formats, process it, and serialize it into another form such as JSON.

Comment: What i think about mapping is to get the properties which are in relation within the ontology files. My question is can we parse all the 10 ontology files and find the the properties which are in relation within other ontology files?